# ios - what is the difference between archiving your application and creating a binary?

Tags: ios, ios5

I have started the steps to submit my app to the apple store, andI have made a keychain security file, and did an archive of the code base.

But as I understand it, I have to make a binary file of the code base which is just a zip file, and upload it to iTunes Connect, is that correct?

What was the point of archiving the codebase? Did that not create the binary? And how do I sign the binary correctly so that it can be submitted to the apple store?

Thanks!!

Comment: The archive is similar to an OSX app bundle, but its also zipped.

Comment: I never thought to create a binary intentionally. When you submit your app, you archive it with sign and submit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating an archive also saves the .dsym files which you need to symbolicate crash reports.

See this article for more about archiving: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1764/_index.html

Comment: thanks - so should I upload the archive file? And how do I make sure that this archive file is signed for the live app upload? Or all the archive files are already ready for live upload?

Comment: You can open the XCode archive organizer and submit your binary from there. When you submit your app you can choose the correct certificate to sign with.

Answer (score 5):

You're using a number of terms here, but not using all of them correctly.

"Code base" usually refers to the entire collection of files that are part of the application. The most important of those are the source code files, but most people would also include such things as XML files, strings files, images, your project file, and other resources. An "archive of the code base" sounds like your put all these in a zip file for safe keeping. I understand you to mean that you used Xcode's 'Archive' command, but this does several things:

- compiles the program into an application bundle (the app bundle is a directory that *includes* the executable "binary" file, but also contains the other resources that the app needs)
- signs the bundle with your private key and distribution provision
- zips the application
- saves the archive along with the debug symbols file in Xcode's organizer so that you can later symbolicate any crash logs you receive
- optionally submits the application to iTunesConnect for review, save the app, or mail the app to someone

"creating a binary" really just means creating some sort of binary (i.e. non-text) file, but it's often understood that the binary file in question is executable. So yes, using Xcode's 'Archive' command will "create a binary", but it goes several steps further in ensuring that the 'binary' is stored in the right format for submitting to iTunesConnect or distributing to users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xcode to submit your binary to iTunes connect. Also, binaries are already signed with the provisioning/distribution profile.

In order to sign the binary correctly, you need to create a distribution profile with the app id you have assigned to your application. You compile your app and make an archive. You can go to Xcode's organizer to submit your application to the app store.

Comment: ah I see, so once I make an archive, what do I do to upload it to iTunes?  And how come iTunes and not the apple store? Thats a bit confusing.  Thanks!!

Comment: iOS apps get uploaded to the iTunes store.  Mac apps get uploaded to the Mac App Store